# PHP Array Unique

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I believe my issue is fairly basic and simple, but I think I am not getting through it.I have a PHP array which has been dynamically populated with data from the database

```
    $PInvoicesList=array();
    $SelectPInvoicesList ="SELECT * FROM AllDataEntriesList 
                            WHERE BusinessID = '{$businessid}' 
                            AND DocumentType = 'purchaseinvoice' 
                            ORDER BY Time ASC;";
    $SelectPInvoicesList_query = mysqli_query($connection, $SelectPInvoicesList);
    if(!$SelectPInvoicesList_query){
        die ("Database query for searching Purchase Invoices failed.".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    while ($SelectPInvoicesList_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($SelectPInvoicesList_query)){

        $PInvoicesList[]=$SelectPInvoicesList_array["DocumentID"];
    }
    array_unique($PInvoicesList);
    print_r($PInvoicesList);
```

And this gives me an array

```
Array ( [0] => pk-000000003-purchaseinvoice-1 
        [1] => pk-000000003-purchaseinvoice-1 
      )
```

When I apply `array_unique($PInvoicesList, SORT_STRING);`, I get both of both elements in the array, whereas they both have the same data. I used this function as `array_unique($PInvoicesList, SORT_REGULAR);` but still both the elements in the array are appearing and they have the exact same data. Can anyone guide me how can I remove the elements with duplicate values from this array?

Comment: Better still show us how this array is created and we can fix it at source rather than frig it after some mistake was made... _Good coding practice by the way, fix error at source_

Comment: Please show us the exact output from `var_dump(PInvoicesList);`. `array_unique()` is the correct function, but your two values are not the same.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thats because this code is getting data from database and this data is actually present in database.

Comment: Regardless of what else is going on, `array_unique($PInvoicesList);` _will not change_ `$PInvoicesList`. `array_unique` _returns_ a new array with the distinct array. It doesn't affect the original array.

Comment: FIX: `SELECT DISTINCT  DocumentID FROM AllDataEntriesList` You will only get one and the query will run faster as you are not returning other columns you have no use for ___Dont fix it, do it right in the first place___

Comment: ^^^^^^ This ^^^^^^  And the one before.

Comment: I hope by pointing that out about `array_unique` that I did not appear to be advocating that as a good solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `array_unique()` removes duplicate values from an array. Just use `array_unique()`

Refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$result = array_unique($PInvoicesList);
```

Comment: How should removing the sorting parameter make a difference?

Comment: This answer is correct because I was making a mistake trying to change the original array, whereas array_unique makes up another array and puts the data inside that new array.

Comment: ___Dont fix up bad ideas. Do it right to start with___

Comment: @RiggsFolly I called all the data from database because I needed more attributes for the same documentid at the same time.

Comment: @Rizier123 - array_unique() default use SORT_REGULAR for sorting. Therefore no need to add manually. Anyway I removed that condition from my answer.